# The linear operator $L:V\to V$ is defined by $L(p(x)) = -6p'(x) - 6p(x)$. How can I find the adjoint $L^{*}$ of $L$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, adjoint-operators

If I'm given an inner produce:

$$\langle p(x),q(x)\rangle = \int_{0}^{1}p(x)q(x)\mathrm{d}x$$

on the vector space $V$ of real polynomials with degree less than $2$.

The linear operator $L:V\to V$ is defined by $L(p(x)) = -6p'(x) - 6p(x)$.

How can I find the adjoint $L^{*}$ of $L$.

I'm not really sure how to start. Any tips?

Comment: The adjoint is the transpose of the matrix. Can you find the matrix that represents the transformations?

Comment: The adjoint $L^*$ must verify $\langle L(p) , q \rangle = \langle p , L^*(q) \rangle $ for all $p,q$.

Comment: The adjoint is defined by the relation $\left< L(p(x)), q(x)\right> = \left< p(x), L^\ast(q(x))\right>$. See if you can write out the left-hand side as the integral of something multiplying $p(x)$.

Comment: What is q(x) supposed to be?

Comment: @CyclotomicField I would avoid reference to "the matrix". Doing so might invite people to consider the matrix with respect to the basis $(1, x, x^2)$, or $(x^2, x, 1)$, and given neither are orthonormal with respect to the inner product, taking the adjoint will produce erroneous results.

Comment: @asdfkasmfa $q(x) \in V$, since the inner product is a bilinear, symmetric, non-degenerate map from $V \times V \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @asdfkasmfa for arbitrary $p, q \in V$, the adjoint $L^*$ is uniquely identified (indeed, defined) by the relationship $\langle L(p(x)), q(x) \rangle = \langle p(x), L^*(q(x)) \rangle$. Expand the LHS, and see in terms of what $L^*$ you could express it.

Comment: As someone who is learning linear algebra, I ask what p′(x) represents here.  Is this the derivative of p(x)?

Comment: @ Joe Shmo ⟨L(p(x)),q(x)⟩ =∫−6p′(x)−6p(x)q(x) =⟨p(x),L∗(q(x))⟩ But what am I supposed to put for q(x)?

Comment: Do these polynomials vanish at $x = 0$ and $x = 1$? If so, you need only apply integration by parts to transfer the derivative from $p$ to $q$.

Answer (score 3):

There's no really simple way to compute adjoints. It tends to be nicer to compute the adjoint on vectors in a basis, rather than deal with the whole thing at once. So, let's compute the adjoint of $x^2$. Using the definition of adjoint,
$$\langle T(p), x^2 \rangle = \langle p, T^*(x^2)\rangle,$$
for all polynomials $p$.

Note: the unknown here is $T^*(x^2)$. We should be able to identify a unique vector $T^*(x^2)$ by considering $p(x) = 1$, then $p(x) = x$, then $p(x) = x^2$ (or any other basis). Let $T^*(x^2) = ax^2 + bx + c$.

If $p(x) = 1$, then we get the equation
\begin{align*}
&\langle T(1), x^2 \rangle = \langle 1, T^*(x^2)\rangle \\
\implies &\int_0^1 -6x^2 \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_0^11 \cdot (ax^2 +bx + c) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
\implies &-2 = \frac{a}{3} + \frac{b}{2} + c. 
\end{align*}
If $p(x) = x$, then
\begin{align*}
&\langle T(x), x^2 \rangle = \langle x, T^*(x^2)\rangle \\
\implies &\int_0^1 (-6x - 6)x^2 \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_0^1x \cdot (ax^2 +bx + c) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
\implies &-\frac{7}{2} = \frac{a}{4} + \frac{b}{3} + \frac{c}{2}. 
\end{align*}
If $p(x) = x^2$, then
\begin{align*}
&\langle T(x^2), x^2 \rangle = \langle x^2, T^*(x^2)\rangle \\
\implies &\int_0^1 (-6x^2 - 12x)x^2 \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_0^1x^2 \cdot (ax^2 +bx + c) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
\implies &-\frac{21}{5} = \frac{a}{5} + \frac{b}{4} + \frac{c}{3}. 
\end{align*}
Now we just solve the system:
$$\left\lbrace \begin{aligned}
\frac{a}{3} + \frac{b}{2} + c &= -2 \\
\frac{a}{4} + \frac{b}{3} + \frac{c}{2} &= -\frac{7}{2} \\
\frac{a}{5} + \frac{b}{4} + \frac{c}{3} &= -\frac{21}{5},
\end{aligned} \right.$$
or the matrix equation
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{2} & 1 \\
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{3}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a \\ b \\ c
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-2 \\ -\frac{7}{2} \\ -\frac{21}{5}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

I strongly recommend finding the inverse to this $3 \times 3$ matrix, as you will be solving a system with the same coefficient matrix two more times (one for $x$ and one for $1$). Computing the inverse, we get
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{2} & 1 \\
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{3}
\end{pmatrix}^{-1} =
\begin{pmatrix}
30 & -180 & 180 \\
-36 & 192 & -180 \\
9 & -36 & 30
\end{pmatrix}.$$
So,
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a \\ b \\ c
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
30 & -180 & 180 \\
-36 & 192 & -180 \\
9 & -36 & 30
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
-2 \\ -\frac{7}{2} \\ -\frac{21}{5}
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
-186 \\ 156 \\ -18
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
So, all in all, we can conclude,
$$T^*(x^2) = -186x^2 + 156x - 18.$$
Next, you can compute $T^*(x)$ and $T^*(1)$ in the same way (and the inverse computed above should be useful once again). Then,
$$T^*(ax^2 + bx + c) = a(-186x^2 + 156x - 18) + bT^*(x) + cT(1),$$
whatever these polynomials happen to be.

---

The alternative is to use CyclotomicField's suggestion and turn it into a matrix. This means you need to:

1. Find an orthonormal basis. This usually involves computing Gram-Schmidt on a basis like $(1, x, x^2)$. This is already a *long* step!
2. Compute the matrix with respect to the basis. Fortunately, when you have an orthonormal basis, this is quite straightforward, as the entries of the matrix will just be inner products (though this still requires some computation).
3. Transpose the matrix (trivial).
4. Write out an arbitrary polynomial $ax^2 + bx + c$ as a coordinate column vector with respect to the orthonormal basis. This is quick and easy, as the basis is orthonormal.
5. Compute the product of the transposed matrix with the coordinate column vector (some computation, but easy enough).
6. Convert this coordinate column vector back to a polynomial (easy).

In total, I'm not convinced it's much quicker!

Answer (score 2):

In all cases, we start from the definition of $L^*$: it's the unique linear operator such that
$$
\langle Lp,q \rangle = \langle p, L^*q \rangle.
$$
Whenever a derivative operator is involved, integration by parts is a way to transfer the derivative to the other side of the product:
$$
\langle p'(x), q(x) \rangle = - \langle p(x), q'(x) \rangle + p(1) q(1) - p(0)q(0).
$$
In particular, for $Lp = -6p' - 6p$, we have
$$
\langle Lp, q \rangle = \langle p, 6q' - 6q \rangle -6\left[p(1) q(1) - p(0) q(0)\right].
$$
Therefore it remains to compute which linear operator $H$ on $V$ corresponds to the equation
$$
\langle p, Hq\rangle = p(1) q(1) - p(0) q(0),
$$
after which the adjoint will be defined by $L^*p = 6p' - 6p - 6Hp$.

The space $V$ is specified here as the space of polynomials of degree less than $2$. In particular, it is a two dimension space with an orthogonal basis is given by $\{p_0, p_1\}$, where $p_0(x) = 1$ and $p_1(x) = \sqrt{12} (x - 1/2)$. You might find it worthwhile to check that this is indeed an orthogonal basis, and also check that you can construct it by applying Gram-Schmidt on the usual polynomial basis $\{1, x\}$.

Then we compute
$$
\langle Hp_0, p_0\rangle = 0, \quad \langle Hp_0, p_1 \rangle = \langle Hp_1,  p_0 \rangle = \sqrt{12}, \quad \langle Hp_1, p_1 \rangle = 0.
$$
In particular, this means that
$$
Hp_0 = H(1) = \sqrt{12} p_1 = 12(x - 1/2),
$$
and
$$
Hp_1 = \sqrt{12}p_0 = \sqrt{12}.
$$
Since we have specified how $H$ acts on a basis of $V$, we have in essence computed it, and as stated before, the adjoint of $L$ is defined by $L^* p = 6p' - 6p - 6Hp$ for $p \in V$.

You might find it worthwhile to explicitly work out a formula for $H$ if it helps you understand how to construct a linear operator based on its matrix representation.

Comment: What if the adjoint has to be in the form L*(a+bx)  = ___ + ___x

Comment: If you compute a formula for $H$ explicitly, then you can give a component-wise formula for $L^*$ as well. Given that you know the values of $H$ on a basis, do you think you can obtain that formula?

Comment: What is the matrix of L supposed to look like by applying the orthonomral basis to it.

Comment: I've given an explicit formula for $L^*$ in terms of $H$, so you can hand calculate. For example $L^*p_0 = 6p_0' - 6p_0 - 6Hp_0$, where $p_0$ is one basis element.

Comment: @Christopher A. Wong I do not understand how you get to $ Hp_0 = H(1) = \sqrt{12} p_1 = 12(x - 1/2), $ and $ Hp_1 = \sqrt{12}p_0 = \sqrt{12}. $  Could you explain this step some more?

Comment: After staring at it some more I see that $\langle \sqrt{12}p_0, p_0 \rangle = \sqrt{12} $ and $\langle \sqrt{12} p_1, p_1 \rangle = \sqrt{12} $ can be used because $p_0$ and $p_1$ are normal. Comparing this to $\langle Hp_0, p_1 \rangle = \langle Hp_1,  p_0 \rangle = \sqrt{12}$ you can get the equations in the next step.